# Heroku release phase bundle not found

Tags: heroku

I have the following release phase in my Procfile:

```
release: bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

It works great when I merge PR's into my staging and production apps, but it fails when running on a new review app. The Heroku docs say that the release phase is run after a successful build, so I don't know why it can't find `bundle`.

This is my output

```
heroku releases:output 9 --app my-app-pr-253
 /bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. It was a silly typo:

```
"buildpacks": [
  {
    "url": "heroku/ruby",
    "url": "https://github.com/guillaume-tgl/heroku-buildpack-ghostscript.git"
  }
]
```

should have been:

```
"buildpacks": [
  { "url": "heroku/ruby"},
  { "url": "https://github.com/guillaume-tgl/heroku-buildpack-ghostscript.git" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Heroku's review apps, you must specify all buildpacks and ENV vars you need in the `app.json` file. You can either manually create one, or have Heroku generate one for you. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#app-json

Confirm that in your `app.json` you have specified

1) The required buildpacks https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/670. Since you are using `bundle` I'm guessing `heroku/ruby` will be one. Below is an example.

```
"buildpacks": [
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git"
  },
```

2) Also make sure you specify any config variables that you want to inherit from the app off which your review app is being built. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#env Missing one of these could also be causing a build to fail.

If neither of these work, try checking the logs for your heroku app. Watch the ones in the Heroku GUI during the build. Also try to tail the logs in the CLI.

`heroku logs -t -a <review_app_name>`

Comment: I have actually done both of these things. It used to work but then it stopped working. I got a response from Heroku but I don't remember what they said about it. I think they basically said that the ghostscript buildpack was probably causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, which got me thinking and helped me find the problem!